# Using solve_ivp for a PDE: how to handle multiple time-dependent variables?

Tags: python, pde, scipy

I am trying to build a Python code that solves a set of coupled differential equations which will be spatially discretized by the method of lines advancing in time. I am planning to use `solve_ivp`. In my problem, the conservation of species includes the product of gas density and mass fraction of species in the time derivative. My question is how do I handle multiple time-dependent variables in a single equation in `solve_ivp`?

one of the equations looks like

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\varepsilon\rho_gY_i\right)+\mathrm{div}\left(\varepsilon\rho_gu_gY_i\right) = \mathrm{div}\left(D_\text{eff}\rho_g\overrightarrow{\mathrm{grad}}\left(Y_i\right)\right)+\dot{\omega_i}
$$

Comment: See example [Lotka-Volterra](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html). It works in the same way. Stack them together in the output vector. Beware, that solve_ivp does not allow a matrix before the time derivative, such as $M \frac{d}{dt}f$ .